# Variable - MySQL Query - Timestamp Converted To Unixtime

Tags: mysql, grafana, grafana-variable

I am using Grafana 8.3.4
In the Dashboard Settings->Variables, I am using MySQL query as the data source.
Even though the values are stored in datetime format in database, it is getting converted to unixtime in variables.

For eg: values in the database - 2022-01-20 05:39:34
Values returned by Grafana - 1642657174000

How to get the values as datetime format?

Comment: This is Grafana "help", it seems - MySQL will do this never. You may convert the datetime to string in SQL query using DATE_FORMAT() function - the datatype of the output column will be string-type and won't be (auto)converted.